# Am i on the right track for muscle up?

Tags: checo, muscle-ups

I have started training to do muscle up yesterday. It is understandable if my shoudle or wrist get pain when i training to do it. But my elbow pain too. Is it ok?

For my dips i could go all the way below my chest. But for my pull up i have difficulty doing it with the false grip. So i use my leg to kick myself up as being told on the website.

http://beastskills.com/tutorials/tutorials/53

Using my leg to kick myself up i am able to get my chest over the pull up bar. But when i tried changing my position from my pull up position to the dips position, i can feel a sharp pain in my elbow. Is it okay to have that sharp pain? Because of that sharp pain i failed all my attempt in trying to get a muscle up done.

Comment: How many pull-ups can you do? How many dips?

Comment: pull up i can do more than 15 haven try pushing to my max rep before. but all the pull up i could not get the bar under my chest. dips i tried doing 20 the other day with the bar go all the way down to almost reaching my neck area.

Comment: As long as those are full-range-of-motion pull-ups, you should be in a great position to work on muscle-ups.

Comment: So it is ok will the pain in my elbow?

Comment: Unfortunately, that I do not know. I've gotten tendonitis when I do too many pull-ups, too.

Comment: think i have to consult a doctor on it soon. hopefully it will be fine. Really wish to do a muscle up.

Comment: Are you keeping your elbows tight to your body during the transition?

Comment: That i did not really notice. In the website i read that we have to lean on to the bar so that we could bring our body over the bar easier. when i lean on to the bar i can feel a very strong force being press down on to my elbow that causes the sharp pain.

Comment: Had just contacted some trainer in my country and ask about the muscle up. He said is either my elbow open too wide or i did not pull high enough to transit to the dip position. Think will be trying it again tonight. If the pain is still there i will go gym for light training instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharp pain in your elbows sounds like a common overuse injury called *Tendinitis*.  Tendinitis is an inflammation of the tendons at your joints.  It will only get worse if you don't deal with it.

- Stop any activity that makes the pain worse.  Both pull ups and dips can cause this pain--which means you'll have to stop working on the muscle up for a while.
- Ice the elbows.  Ice helps reduce the inflammation.
- Use NSAIDs ([Non-Steroidal Anti-Inflammatory Drug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-steroidal_anti-inflammatory_drug)) initially, also to help with the inflammation.
- When pain has ceased, re-introduce activity with light weights and high reps.  This helps to get blood flowing through the area further removing the remaining inflammation.  A good exercise for this stage is the [Unilateral Dumbbell Floor Press](http://www.t-nation.com/readArticle.do?id=4863755).  Do not bend the elbow past 90 degrees during rehabilitation.

It may take as long as 6 weeks to get back to normal.  You can train around this overuse injury, meaning you will have to stick to exercises that don't make it worse.

Comment: okay thanks. Never have thought just this 2 day of pushing will cause such problem. think i have to go back to gym for the next few week before i can continue with my training for muscle up.

Comment: I just stumbled on this link.  Might give it a try for the tendinitis: http://www.mobilitywod.com/2012/04/banish-your-elbow-pain-you-dont-really-play-golf-or-tennis-do-you.html

Comment: look useful. will have to see when my friend is free to help me with that. thanks.